# Strange conditions in the generated SQL query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm working on some EF query optimization. To better understand query performance, I'm looking into generated SQL, and some conditions makes me crazy:

```
WHERE (cast(1 as bit) <> cast(0 as bit))...
```

I can't imagine a case, when this condition will evaluate to false. Also:

```
CASE WHEN ([Extent9].[Id] IS NULL) THEN...
```

Obviously, [Extent9].[Id] means primary key column in the corresponding table, which, of course, can't be `NULL`.

Why these conditions present in SQL?
Here's LINQ query text, if it can help answer the question:

```
var query = _context
    .Objects
    .Where(o => o.DatawareVersionId == _datawareId);
    .SelectMany(t => t.ComplexSubTasks)
    .Where(st => st.Variant.Order.CurrentAlgoVersion != null)
    .Select(st => st.Variant.Order.CurrentAlgoVersion)
    .OfType<MonitoringAlgoVersion>()
    .Where(version => version != null && version.Applicabilities.Any(applicability => applicability.SymbolicCircuitTypeId == _typeId))
    .Any());
    .Select(o => o.Group)
    .Distinct();
```

**UPDATE**.
Entire SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
[Distinct1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Distinct1].[GenericGroup] AS [GenericGroup], 
[Distinct1].[Number] AS [Number], 
[Distinct1].[Group] AS [Group]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[GenericGroup] AS [GenericGroup], 
    [Extent2].[Number] AS [Number], 
    [Extent2].[Group] AS [Group]
    FROM  [dbo].[Objects] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ObjectGroups] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[GroupId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[DatawareVersionId] = @p__linq__0) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent9].[Id] AS [Id]
            FROM       [dbo].[Tasks] AS [Extent3]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[SubTasks] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent4].[TaskId]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Variants] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[VariantId] = [Extent5].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[OrderId] = [Extent6].[Id]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[AlgoVersions] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[CurrentAlgoVersion] = [Extent7].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent5].[OrderId] = [Extent8].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AlgoVersions] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[CurrentAlgoVersion] = [Extent9].[Id]
            WHERE (cast(1 as bit) <> cast(0 as bit)) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[ObjectId]) AND (CASE WHEN ([Extent9].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE '10X0X' END LIKE '10X0X%')
        )  AS [Project1]
        WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [apot].[draw_algo_versions_applicability] AS [Extent10]
            WHERE ([Project1].[Id] = [Extent10].[algo_version_id]) AND ([Extent10].[schema_type_id] = @p__linq__1)
        )
    ))
)  AS [Distinct1]
```

**UPDATE 2**.
Here's entity types, mapped to `AlgoVersions` table:

```
public abstract class AlgoVersion : VersionedEntity
{           
    public virtual int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsErrorFixed { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsFunctionalityExtended { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableCollection<AlgoVersionStatus> Statuses { get; set; }
}

public class MonitoringAlgoVersion : AlgoVersion
{
    public virtual ObservableCollection<TemplateGroup> TemplateGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableCollection<MonitoringAlgoVersionApplicability> Applicabilities { get; set; }
}
```

where `VersionedEntity` is a base class for entities, which have an `Id` and `ObjectVersion` (both `Entity` and `VersionedEntity` are not mapped to any table):

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class VersionedEntity : Entity
{
    public virtual byte[] ObjectVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire generated SQL statement?  Hard to deduce the context of those two clauses in isolation.

Comment: can you post the `AlgoVersions` class?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *why* `cast(1 as bit) <> cast(0 as bit)` is there but there is [a work item in the EF backlog to remove this](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/200). I would recommend voting for it. I imagine this means its completely useless as the item is posted by RoMiller. Its pretty common in queries, I've seen it before often.